# bundle updated then sprockets throw filenotfound error rails 3.2.3 ruby1.9.3p194

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have been running Rails 3.2.3 everything ran fine. Last night I did a bundle update to update every thing in my Gemfile and here's the update log.

```
Updating git://github.com/stefants/negative-captcha.git
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Installing multi_json (1.3.4) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Installing sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Installing tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Installing addressable (2.2.8) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Installing json (1.7.1) with native extensions 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using rails (3.2.3) 
Using awesome_nested_fields (0.6.0) 
Using xml-simple (1.1.1) 
Using aws-s3 (0.6.2) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Installing bson (1.6.2) 
Installing bson_ext (1.6.2) with native extensions 
Installing business_time (0.6.1) 
Using cancan (1.6.7) 
Installing carrierwave (0.6.2) 
Installing mongo (1.6.2) 
Installing mongoid (2.4.9) 
Installing carrierwave-mongoid (0.2.0) 
Using chronic (0.6.7) 
Installing cocoon (1.0.20) 
Installing coderay (1.0.6) 
Installing coffee-script-source (1.3.1) 
Installing execjs (1.3.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using coffeebeans (1.0.1) 
Using datejs-rails (1.1.0) 
Installing delayed_job (3.0.2) 
Using delayed_job_mongoid (1.0.8) 
Using orm_adapter (0.0.7) 
Using warden (1.1.1) 
Using devise (2.0.4) 
Using ejs (1.0.0) 
Using eventmachine (0.12.10) 
Using em-websocket (0.3.6) 
Installing excon (0.13.4) 
Using faker (1.0.1) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.7.6) 
Using ffi (1.0.11) 
Using formatador (0.2.1) 
Using net-ssh (2.3.0) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.2) 
Using ruby-hmac (0.4.0) 
Using fog (1.3.1) 
Using git (1.2.5) 
Using term-ansicolor (1.0.7) 
Installing grizzled-rails-logger (0.1.3) 
Using rb-appscript (0.6.1) 
Using growl_notify (0.0.3) 
Installing guard (1.0.2) 
Using guard-livereload (0.4.2) 
Using hirb (0.6.2) 
Using humane-rails (2.8.0.0.1.2) 
Using jeweler (1.8.3) 
Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Installing jquery-ui-rails (0.4.0) 
Using kaminari (0.13.0) 
Using knockout-rails (1.0.1) 
Using method_source (0.7.1) 
Using momentjs-rails (1.5.0) 
Using mongoid-data_table (1.3.3) 
Using mongoid-eager-loading (0.3.1) 
Using negative-captcha (0.1.0) from git://github.com/stefants/negative-captcha.git (at master) 
Using nifty-generators (0.4.6) 
Installing oauth (0.4.6) 
Using oauth2 (0.5.2) 
Using typhoeus (0.3.3) 
Using panda (1.5.0) 
Using slop (2.4.4) 
Installing pry (0.9.9.4) 
Using pry-rails (0.1.6) 
Installing rails-backbone (0.7.2) 
Using rb-fchange (0.0.5) 
Installing rb-fsevent (0.9.1) 
Using rb-inotify (0.8.8) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Installing sass (3.1.17) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Installing simple_form (2.0.2) 
Installing simple_oauth (0.1.7) 
Using stripe (1.6.3) 
Installing stylus-source (0.26.0) 
Installing stylus (0.5.1) 
Using uglifier (1.2.4) 
Using underscore-rails (1.3.1) 
Using webshims-rails (0.1) 
Using wirble (0.1.3) 
Using youtube_it (2.1.4) 
Using zero-clipboard-rails (1.0.1) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Then I restarted the server and now Sprockets::FileNotFound errors are thrown for some @import "file.css" line in my sass files.

I did some research on the Sprockets gem, I found that the current version is 2.4.2. But my bundle update updated the sprockets to 2.1.3. Is this what is out there for your Rails apps, too, that the sprockets used by Rails is a few versions behind Github's? -- And how should I approach this Sprockets::FileNotFound problem?

APPEND: I just also saw that the sprockets in the gemfile.lock to be of version 2.1.2. yet bundle show sprockets says 2.1.3.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove `Gemfile.lock` (backup first) and run `bundle install` once again